# How to get the value from .pm/xml from Makefile

Tags: perl, makefile

In a .pm file I have a hash `%DIFF_VARIABLES` and would like to extract the value of `$DIFF_VARIABLES{'MAIN'}{'value'}`.

I would like to execute this from Makefile.

I am trying this in the Makefile

```
MY_VAR := ($shell perl -Mconfig -e "$DIFF_VARIABLES{'MAIN'}{'value'}" /home/my_path/TEST_MODULE_1.pm)
```

But it is not working.

I tried different ways, but I think I am making a mistake.

---

Based on Below suggestion I tried this, but still its not working for me.. 
so here is what I did. I created a separate perl file where I placed the code which is looking for desired value from PERL Module. Now, in Makefile I execute that perl file

But still it is NOT working......

in Makefile here is what I did -

```
// comment --Lets say VAR_1's value came as 2.

VAR_1 = $(shell perl ./my_new_perl_file.pl) export VAR_1

ifeq ($(VAR_1), 1) ...do task1 else ..do task2 endif
```

But it is not working... If I explicitly define VAR_1 = 1 in top of the makefile, then it is working...

Any suggestion? pls..

Comment: Is the `%DIFF_VARIABLES` hash in your module a lexical variable (defined with `my`) or a package variable (defined with `our` or `use vars`)?

Comment: It is package variable - defined with 'our'

Comment: You will have to show the contents of `TEST_MODULE_1.pm`. What you have written passes the .pm file as input to the Perl command, but it is never read. You need to *execute* the module for the hash to gain a value.

Comment: Borodin -  that is what I dont know - executing .pm from makefile to gain the value.  TEST_MODULE_1.pm is the package in which HASH -DIFF_VARIABLES is defined as package variable..

Comment: @Vijayc: It will be easier to help if we can see the contents of your Perl module and `my_new_perl_file.pl`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `print` the value in order for it to be passed out to your calling process. Here's a really simple package:

```
package Value;

our %DIFF_VARIABLES = (
  MAIN => { value => 'foo' },
);

1;
```

To print that value in a shell, we can use code like this:

```
$ perl -MValue -E'say $Value::DIFF_VARIABLES{MAIN}{value}'
foo
```

We can assign it to a shell variable like this:

```
$ VALUE=`perl -MValue -E'say $Value::DIFF_VARIABLES{MAIN}{value}'`
$ echo $VALUE
foo
```

And you can probably build on that (using `$(shell ...)`) to do something similar in your Makefile.

Comment: Thanks for reply Dave. I am trying what you suggested, but seems not working for me... doing some exp on top of it. Will post my updates..